# R Markdown, GGplot showing up above header

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I know that its best to include a reproducible example, but I'm not sure how I would do that in this instance and unfortunately the data and rest of the .rmd document includes some PHI so I can't include that, but hopefully you can still help me:

I have a document I'm knitting to PDF in R.  Here is a screenshot of my code with the headings above the graph:
[image]

When I knit it, here's the output:
[image]

I.e. the graph is showing up above the "Count" heading.  What the heck?  I've tried various odd formatting tricks (adding blank line in between by Visuals header and my count header, etc..)  and nothing.

The graph right below it has the same problem (Percent graph is above percent heading), but all the rest of the graphs in my document (18 page pdf) show up where they are supposed to, and here is my code at the top of the document:

[image]

Anyone experienced something similar?  Any idea where to even start fixing it?